# send email from my local domain example.com to external mail server using Sendmail

Tags: email, sendmail

I'm using Sendmail as an MTA. I setup a local domain example.org, everything is running well, so now I want to use this local mail server to send email to my Gmail account or any external server. Just sending not receiving.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. You might want to read our [how to ask](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Have you tried anything? Did you search for how to do this? This site is for solving specific problems not for giving howtos.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: If you want just to send mails, then sendmail is quite overkill. Take a look at [sSMTP](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSMTP), it may be more sufficient for you.

Answer (score 1):

I found this tutorial which gives you a setup which will forward all email to a single GMail account. The article is titled:[Forwarding all email to a domain with sendmail](http://www.bitsofpancake.com/server-admin/forwarding-all-email-to-a-domain-with-sendmail/).

1. Changes to `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc`

   Change this:

   ```
   DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet, Name=MTA-v4, Port=smtp, Addr=127.0.0.1')dnl
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet, Name=MTA-v4, Port=smtp')dnl
   ```
2. Enable virtusertable, again in the file: `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc`

   ```
   FEATURE(`virtusertable',`hash -o /etc/mail/virtusertable.db')dnl
   ```
3. Create `/etc/mail/virtusertable`

   ```
   @example.com    forwardtothisemail@gmail.com
   ```
4. Compile the virtusertable

   ```
   $ cd /etc/mail
   $ sudo makemap hash virtusertable < virtusertable
   ```
5. Add domain to `/etc/mail/local-host-names`

   ```
   example.com
   ```
6. Recompile sendmail.mc

   *Ubuntu*

   ```
   $ sudo sendmailconfig
   ```

   *Fedora/CentOS/RHEL*

   ```
   $ cd /etc/mail
   $ make
   $ /etc/init.d/sendmail restart
   ```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to respond, apparently that will works, i will try it this night & i will report a feedback.